# Count nodes by comparing attribute values

Tags: xslt, xpath

Say I have a list of colors like this:

```
<colors>
  <color>Red</color>
  <color>Green</color>
  <color>Blue</color>
</colors>
```

And I have any number of items each of which can have a color:

```
<items>
  <item color="Blue"/>
</items>
```

Now I want to show for each color how many items there are with that color:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//color">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>: <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[@color = ...])"/>&#10;
</xsl:for-each>
No color: <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[not(@color)])"/>
```

But I have no idea how to select all the items by comparing them to the current color. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to link to the items by their color. For example, given:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <colors>
        <color>Red</color>
        <color>Green</color>
        <color>Blue</color>
    </colors>
    <items>
        <item color="Red"/>
        <item color="Green"/>
        <item color="Blue"/>
        <item color="Green"/>
        <item color="Blue"/>
        <item color="Blue"/>
    </items>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-color" match="item" use="@color" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="colors/color">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('item-by-color', .))"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
Red: 1
Green: 2
Blue: 3
```

---

If you also want to count items with no color, change the key definition to:

```
<xsl:key name="item-by-color" match="item" use="string(@color)" />
```

then use:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(key('item-by-color', ''))"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I was missing something. I assume it's not possible without a key?

Comment: It is possible, if you do `<xsl:value-of select="count(/root/items/item[@color=current()])"/>`. But is not only less elegant, it is also less efficient.